# Wireless AP placement

Tags: wireless, design, ubiquiti

Attaching office studio layout with my proposed Ubiquiti AP placement. All 28 desks occupied with heavy WiFi users that like to complain;)

Is the placement the best possible?

Do you think that one UniFi AP is enough or shall I install two?

Edit: Orange wall is made of wooden shelves, so not actually a wall. I don't know why it is marked orange on the drawing.

[image: studio]

Comment: Decided, following @Johnny advise I will 'right around where those 2 black dots are on the diagram, maybe moving them one seat closer to the top of the diagram.'

Issue is that I'm planning to mount them in an easy way, so on a wooden beam that is just around 2.3m above the floor. Is this height enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with two nodes so if one fails or reboots, the other can take over.

For such a small office, I wouldn't bother hiring someone to do a wireless site survey unless you're in a very noise RF environment. For what you'd pay for a site survey, you can just hang another node or two. Just place the nodes temporarily where you think you want them, then walk around and see how well they work.

Hang them on the ceiling if possible, most of the Unifi nodes have antennas that are optimized for ceiling mounting. PoE power means just running an ethernet cable above the drop ceiling to the node (or running a cable along pipes or beams if you have an exposed ceiling)

I'd probably hang them right around where those 2 black dots are on the diagram, maybe moving them one seat closer to the top of the diagram to put them more central and provide better coverage through the wall to the conference room. If that wall is particularly solid (i.e. metal reinforced concrete) you may end up having to put a node in the conference room, but regular office walls (even with metal studs) shouldn't be a problem.

I've found that the Unifi controller is not good at auto-channel assignment so make sure the nodes aren't using overlapping channels.

Comment: Thank you @Johnny, your answer is perfect. Please not my question edit in regards of the orange wall, these are just wooden shelves. does it change anything?

Comment: That doesn't really change anything, though you may need to adjust the position of the node nearest the conference room to make sure the oval table isn't in an RF shadow from the kitchen walls.

Comment: yes @Johnny, good note about the kitchen wall. Won't the radio signal bounce from walls to cover the round table?

Comment: @FoxReymann, bouncing radio waves are a source of problems, causing [Multipath Interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipath_interference). This is one of the problems a wireless site survey can predict, which will help you with WAP placement. Also, you need to find out if there are WAPs directly under or over your workspace which are on the floor(s) above or below. Radio is a three-dimensional medium, and this can cause a lot of interference with your Wi-Fi..

Answer (score 2):

As @RonMaupin says, the best way to answer your question is with a wireless survey.  But as a first approximation, the best place to put your AP is in the center of the room.  If all 28 chairs are using wifi, then having more that one AP will improve your performance -- in that case you spread the APs out.   Also, the AP speed settings can help improve your performance.

Answer (score 0):

That's what wireless site surveys are for. You should hire someone with the proper knowledge and equipment to perform the survey, which will tell you the quantity, placement, frequencies, radio power, etc. that you should use for the best performance and to reduce or eliminate radio shadows.

Having us look at a map is merely a guessing game without knowing what else is going on in the airwaves there.

Answer (score 0):

You could do your own wireless survey and then select the best channels to use for your two WAPs. 
Here is a discussion on doing your own survey:-

http://community.ubnt.com/t5/UniFi-Wireless/Using-Unifi-AP-for-site-surveys/m-p/775750#M59596

Unless your clients cannot do 802.11a don't advertise anything in the 2.4GHz range...you'll receive complaints when someone uses the microwave or some other interferer.

For load balancing the clients, here is another discussion that may help:-
https://community.ubnt.com/t5/UniFi-Wireless/How-to-load-balance-with-Unifi-AP/td-p/1259634